# Most elegant way to create an entity with two references without using mass assignment

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following setup of entities (User, Rating, Post)

- user has many posts
- user has many ratings
- post has many ratings
- post belongs to user
- rating belongs to user
- rating belongs to post

I'm looking for a good way to create a new rating. Usually for posts for example I'd do something like:

```
Auth::user()->posts()->create(...);
```

To ensure a correct references for the user. However, now I have two Objects that I want to include. I don't want to allow mass assignment of the id - e.g.

```
Auth::user()->ratings()->create(['value' => 1, 'post_id' => 1, ...])
```

or

```
$post->ratings()->create(['value' => 1, 'user_id' => 1, ...])
```

I also would prefer to not set everything manually since it makes the code "unclean"

```
$rating = new Rating;
$rating->user = Auth::user();
$rating->post = $post; 
$rating->value = 1;
$rating->save();
```

Is there a way to make all of this inline?

Comment: something is wrong there....you should save a value and not the relationship...

Comment: ofcourse there will be a value - but saving a value is not my problem. I reduced the code to what is actually relevant - i ll quickly add the value